# git add file from directory

Tags: git

I am new to git and am having trouble adding a `.java` file to my repository.

I created a repo named `Enrollment` and want to add a file named `classes.java` to this repo, but can't get it to work.

It is in a folder called `classeslist` on the desktop; what would the add command for something like this look like?

Most tutorials seem to skip this part. I assumed it would just be `git add classes.java`.

Comment: Try `git add <fullpath>`. Make sure you're not gitnoring them.

Comment: so it would be git add Users/desktop/classeslist/signup/classes.java if that was the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the file to your project folder and then you will be able to add it.

> It is in a file called `classeslist` on the desktop

Git can only add files located under the **root** folder of the project so you have to copy it to there.

This is how it works in git:

```
git add
git commit
```

[image]

---

## ***`git add`***

As a best practice if you wish to add all your files at once use the `git add -A .`.
The `-A` will also add all removed files and moved files as well.

Comment: So I could put it in the classeslist folder, but in no subfolders?  What would the add command look like for this?  I know this is basic, but I'm doing something wrong and can't find a clear answer.

Comment: You can put it anywhere you like, in the root, in a subfolder as long as its under the root folder of your project. example: `<root folder>a/b/c/file` or just a `<root folder>/file`

Comment: Ok, I think I may have figured it out.  So to work with git in my classeslist folder I need to navigate there in the command line and then initialize it there with git init?

Comment: exactly.

but since its on your desktop i dont think you wish to add all your desktop files as well. it will be better to create an empty folder and move the desire files to ti and use git init there.

Comment: Since You are new user do this cool tutorial for 10 minutes. It will answer all your questions.

http://try.github.com

Comment: Yes, I started there, must have missed the first steps though.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I can see that you are a new user to StackOverflow as well. So here is how the site works in a nutshell: Once you get the answer which helped you the most you should accept it. you can also vote for it and for any other answers which you wish. but it's important to accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is your project initialized with git? If not, do these:

1. git init.
2. git status to show the changed files.
3. git add to add the files.
4. git commit to create a new commit.

You can check if your folder is git initialized if the root folder has a .git hidden folder.